# How to get a an audio file from android and save it as a file in server instead of database using webservice-j2ee

Tags: android, web-services

i want to pass an audio file from android project to dynamic web application project in java. now instead of creating database as backend i want to create  a folder in server to save this audio file.... can anyone plz help me how to save a .mp3  file in a folder in server... my code is as follows

```
package com.android.audio.mediaplayer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import com.android.qrcode.db.AudioVideoServer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;



public class AudioRecord  extends Activity
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
    private static String mFileName = null;
    public String AudioFile;

    private RecordButton mRecordButton = null;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

    private PlayButton   mPlayButton = null;
    private MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;
    private SubmitButton mSubmitButton = null;
    private String url = "postLoginData.do?do=postLoginData";
    String result;
    byte[] value;
    String s;

    private void onRecord(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startRecording();
        } else {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }

    private void onPlay(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startPlaying();
        } else {
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }
    /* public boolean saveas(int ressound){  
             byte[] buffer=null;  
             InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);  
             int size=0;  

             try {  
              size = fIn.available();  
              buffer = new byte[size];  
              fIn.read(buffer);  
             fIn.close();  
            } catch (IOException e) {  
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            return false;  
            }  

            String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";  
            String filename="examplefile"+".ogg";  

            boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();  
            if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}  

            FileOutputStream save;  
            try {  
             save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);  
             save.write(buffer);  
             save.flush();  
             save.close();  
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
             return false;  
            } catch (IOException e) {  
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
             return false;  
            }      

            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));  

            File k = new File(path, filename);  

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());  
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "exampletitle");  
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");  
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "cssounds ");  
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);  
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);  
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);  
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);  

            //Insert it into the database  
            this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);  


            return true;  
           }  */
    private void stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }

    class RecordButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartRecording = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onRecord(mStartRecording);
                if (mStartRecording) {
                    setText("Stop recording");
                } else {
                    setText("Start recording");
                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
            }
        };

        public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start recording");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    class PlayButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartPlaying = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPlay(mStartPlaying);
                if (mStartPlaying) {
                    setText("Stop playing");
                } else {
                    setText("Start playing");
                }
                mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
            }
        };

        public PlayButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start playing");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }
    class SubmitButton extends Button {

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                byte[] file = mFileName.getBytes();
                System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$" + file);
                s = Base64.encodeToString(file, MODE_APPEND);
                System.out.println("**************" + s);

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Audiofile.mp3", s));
                result = AudioVideoServer.executePost(url, nameValuePairs);

            }
        };

        public SubmitButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Save");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    public AudioRecord() {
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
         //mImagePath = b.getString("path");
        AudioFile = b.getString("audiofile");

        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName +=AudioFile; 
            //"/audiorecordtest.mp4";
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        mRecordButton = new RecordButton(this);
        ll.addView(mRecordButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                0));
        mPlayButton = new PlayButton(this);
        ll.addView(mPlayButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                0));
        mSubmitButton = new SubmitButton(this);
        ll.addView(mSubmitButton, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0));


        setContentView(ll);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to implement file upload functionality in a Java EE application is to utilize the restlet framework, which has an [extension](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/28-restlet/64-restlet.html) for file uploading. This extension is based on Apache's [FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).

You can find some examples for FileUpload [here](http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet-file-upload-example.html) and [here](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/java-upload/).

If you are using Tomcat 7 or any other Servlet 3.0 container, then file uploading functionality is built-in. See [here](http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet3/multipartconfig-file-upload-example.html) for an example.

Comment: thanks kgiannakakis, can u plz give me sample sites for reffering how to work it out with FileUpload